# Use IN param in WHERE clause inside MySQL stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, parameter-passing, heidisql

I am using MySQL with HeidiSQL and I want to create a stored procedure that takes one String param and returns a table. This is what I have tried:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp(IN in_param VARCHAR(50))
BEGIN
  SELECT * FROM fact_table ft
  WHERE ft.param = @in_param
END
```

And I called it like this:

```
CALL sp('string_param');
```

The procedure returns an empty table, as `@in_param` is somehow `NULL` inside the SP.

I also like this: `WHERE ft.param = in_param`, but the I got an error when I ran it, saying `SQL Error (1054): Unknown column 'in_param' in 'where clause'`

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

PS: 
I tried creating it by hand, and also using Heidi's Create new -> Stored routine wizard

Comment: When I do selects etc within a MySQL stored procedure I don't normally have the @ symbol before the variable - also are you expecting the stored procedure to return the rows - by default it won't do this.

Comment: Well, I tried modifying it to remove the in_param, and then removed the WHERE clause, and it had no problem in returning the select result.

Comment: You are missing a semi-colon (;) after the select statement and you should drop the @.

Comment: Yes, you were right about the semi-colon, thanks. But dropping the '@' still doesn't fix it. I talked about this option in the original post

Answer (score 1):

I finally found out a solution that works:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp(IN in_param VARCHAR(50))
BEGIN
  DECLARE declared_in_param CHAR(50);
  SET declared_in_param = in_param;
  SELECT * FROM fact_table ft
  WHERE ft.param = declared_in_param;
END
```

So, the idea was to declare and set a new variable to that IN param, and use that declared variable inside the WHERE clause of the SELECT statement.

I haven't had time to research WHY this works, but I will